# Is there not a urdf utitlity package(liburdfom-dev or liburdfom-tools) in noetic?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to install urdf utility package to check_urdf command for my .urdf files. And when I try to install the utility package using the following commands

```
sudo apt-get install liburdfom-tools
```

or

```
sudo apt-get install liburdfom-dev
```

I get the following result

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package liburdfom-tools/dev #depending on the command
```

Am I doing something wrong or does the urdf utility package not exist in noetic?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/386521/is-there-not-a-urdf-utitlity-package(liburdfom-dev-or-liburdfom-tools)-in-noetic?/) by [abhijelly](https://answers.ros.org/users/84774/abhijelly/) on ROS Answers with karma: 18 on 2021-09-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This package needs to be built from source. Refer to this tutorial:

http://wiki.ros.org/ROSberryPi/Installing%20ROS%20Indigo%20on%20Raspberry%20Pi

For example,

`$ cd ~/ros_catkin_ws/external_src`

`$ sudo apt-get install libboost-test-dev libtinyxml-dev`

`$ git clone https://github.com/ros/urdfdom.git`

`$ cd urdfdom`

`$ cmake .`

`$ sudo checkinstall make install`

Hope this helps you

---

Originally posted by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) with karma: 1650 on 2021-09-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [abhijelly](https://answers.ros.org/users/84774/abhijelly/) on 2021-09-16**:
Hello! This helped, thank you! I am also trying to check my urdf using the package "urdfdom_py" but the terminal says this package cannot be found. I was wondering if you know anything about this package, if not I appreciate your reply!

PS command I am trying to run

##### This provides a JSON version of the robot, but crashes when the description has erros. Review the errors to  fix the URDF file.

```
rosrun urdfdom_py display urdf robot_des.urdf
```

**Comment by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) on 2021-09-16**:
Vote on this issue please to close the question.  Remember is 1 Question 1 Answer. For your next question, also remember to search for prior answers. Glad it was able to help.